# Generatrix visible in RevolutionPlot3D with thickness

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to plot an open cone (without the base) with a certain thickness. I have first tried with `RevolutionPlot3D` as follows:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{t, t}, {t, 0, 1}, Mesh -> 100, 
 MeshStyle -> Transparent, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 2}}]
```

However, the generatrix is visible for some reasons:
[image]

I have then tried with `Graphics3D` and `Cone`:

```
Graphics3D[{Cone[], Thickness[0.1]}, ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, 1, 1}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

But changing the thickness doesn't seem to change anything.
Is there any hidden function to hide the generatrix in `RevolutionPlot3D`? I understand though that ideally I should use the function `Cone` since it is less heavy in memory.

Comment: Removing the option PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]} gets rid of most of the line. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. That would indeed work, but I need a minimum of transparency for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. `RevolutionPlot3D` treats the surface like it were not isotrop in the x y plane, having an edge along the generatrix.

To circumvent this, we may use `RegionPlot3D` instead of `RevolutionPlot3D`:

```
wall = 0.04;
RegionPlot3D[(z - wall) <= 
  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= (z + wall), {x, -1 - wall, 
  1 + wall}, {y, -1 - wall, 1 + wall}, {z, -wall, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]], 
 PlotRange -> (1 + wall) {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly!